# Multi field array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, dbi

Using Perl and DBI to get data from SQL database.  I am using the code below to get data from a table.   Instead of defining 3 different arrays, is there a way to define an array with multiple fields?

```
$sql = "select * from tblPeople where PersonID=?";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($PID);

while ($DRow = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    push @KnownPIDs,  $DRow->{PersonID};
    push @Knownoss,   $DRow->{currentpos};
    push @Knownnotes, $DRow->{personnotes};
}
```

Comment: Please show your table schema and an example of the desired result array.

Comment: tblPeople, fields Personid, currentpos, personnotes.    Not sure of the array result because I don't what is available in Perl.

Comment: Anything should be possible, if you don't know what you want how can the question be answered?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, is use the keys of the DRow hash as keys for a new HoA hash, and dynamically make each value of HoA an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;

my %HoA; # hash of arrays
my $DRow = {};

# set up some example data

$DRow->{PersonID} = 'steve';
$DRow->{currentpos} = 'one';
$DRow->{personnotes} = 'This is not my suicide note';

# by using a Hash of Arrays (HoA), we can dynamically build
# the entire structure without having to manually type everything 
# out for each row item

for my $key (keys(%{ $DRow })){
    push @{ $HoA{$key} }, $DRow->{$key};
}

# to access the 'PersonID' of say the third row that was processed:
# my $pid = $HoA{PersonID}->[2];

print Dumper \%HoA;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'personnotes' => [
                             'This is not my suicide note'
                           ],
          'PersonID' => [
                             'steve'
                        ],
          'currentpos' => [
                            'one'
                          ]
        };
```